# For Diffie-Hellman, why is a g value of p−1 not a suitable choice?

Tags: key-exchange, diffie-hellman

I am currently learning about the Diffie-Hellman key exchange. I understand that for a $g$ of $1$, the resulting key would always end up as $1$ which would obviously not be secure.

I read that the $p\! -\! 1$ value for $g$ is not secure either, but there is no explanation as to why - which is my question. I guess it has to do with $g$ being a divisor of $p\! -\! 1$ but I am not sure.

Comment: Oh, this talk about the generator $g$. A generator with low order will not be secure. that is why one considers the safe primes for the modulus.

Comment: Note: I rolled back to an earlier revision because [revision 7](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/77868/7) had little to do with the initial question, and was overly general.

Answer (score 8):

If $g=p-1$ then $g\equiv -1\pmod p$ that is $g$ is effectively the same as $-1$ which has the obvious drawback that $g^x$ can only ever be $+1$ or $p-1$ which is easily brute-forcable.

---

Here's a short proof sketch of the above exponentiation statement:

\begin{align}
 (p-1)^2\bmod p  &= (p^2-2p+1)\bmod p \\
  &=(p^2\bmod p)-(2p\bmod p)+(1\bmod p)\\ 
  &= 0-0+1\\
\end{align}

So when you have $(p-1)^x\bmod p$ this is the same as $(p-1)^{2y}\cdot(p-1)^{z}\bmod p$ for $x=2y+z$ and $z\in \{0,1\}$ which is $((p-1)^2)^y\cdot (p-1)^{z}\bmod p=1^y\cdot (p-1)^{z}$ which is either $p-1$ or $1$.

Comment: $(p-1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}p^{n-k}(-1)^k = (-1)^n + p\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n \choose k}p^{n-k-1}(-1)^k$, that is, the last term of the sum (when $k = n$) is the only one that is not a multiple of $p$, as a consequence, $(p-1)^n \mod p = (-1)^n$.

Comment: @JohnMichaels that is modular arithmetic. Normally, It is an equivalence class and each element is represented by $[0],[1],[2],\ldots,[p-1]$. For convenience, the square brackets are removed. You can freely choose any element to represent the equivalence class and using $-1$ in some situations is very helpful instead of $p-1$. to see that $-1$ has is in the same equivalence class, just add $p$ there you will see that that it is $p-1$, also $2p-1$, i.e. $-1 \equiv p-1 \equiv 2p-1 \pmod p$